# Deserializing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, deserialization

```
private void SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    class Write implements Serializable
    {
        int retreivalid;
        String name;
        String account_name;
        String userid;
        String password;
        Object date1;

        public String getname()
        {
           return name;              
        }

        public String getuserid()
        {
           return userid;
        }
    }    

    JFileChooser o=new JFileChooser();
    int l=o.showSaveDialog(null);
    o.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("PLO Files","PLO"));
    if(l==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File filesave=o.getSelectedFile();
        filepath=filesave.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    System.out.println("the filepath is:" + filepath);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<19;i++)
    {
        Write[] wer=new Write[100];  
        wer[i]=new Write();
        wer[i].retreivalid=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tabledetails.getValueAt(j,0)));
        wer[i].name=(String)tabledetails.getValueAt(j,1);
        wer[i].account_name=(String)tabledetails.getValueAt(j,2);
        wer[i].userid=(String)tabledetails.getValueAt(j,3);
        wer[i].password=(String)tabledetails.getValueAt(j,4);
        wer[i].date1=tabledetails.getValueAt(j,5);
        j++;
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(wer[i]);
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(filepath);
            ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            Write wt=(Write) is.readObject();
            System.out.println(wt.getname() + "," + wt.getuserid());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("THe details of exception are" + e);
        }
    }
```

I am making a password manager and I am working on saving persons data in a file.The data has been saved but now I have to deserialize for open button as the user will open the file and see content.In this the code from the line containing fileInputstream till end are giving exceptions.So can anybody tell me what mistake I have made.note that serialisation has been properly done and the plo file is getting created with object written.PLO file is a file extension which I  just have created for this project?

Comment: Exceptions? Do you mean compilation errors instead? In any case, any potential helpers will want to know what are the error messages.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 3) What is the point of setting a file filter after the file chooser has been sown (and dismissed)?